# Filter stream with values from another stream

Tags: java, java-8

I have a hard time coming up with a universal solution to my problem. Let's suppose I have a complex data structure D. I want to find all elements in D that satisfies a predicate P with given filter values F and store the result in a Stack.
I came up with two distinct solutions for positive and negative predicates.

```
List<Integer> sample = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("4","5","6");

BiPredicate<Integer, String> predicate = (d,f) -> d.equals(Integer.valueOf(f));
Function<Integer, Integer> converter = Function.identity();

Collection<Integer> filtered = sample.parallelStream()
                                     .filter(d -> values.parallelStream()
                                                        .anyMatch(f -> predicate.test(d, f)))
                                     .map(converter::apply)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Stack::new));
```

The problem:
The above approach works as long as my predicate is negative. In the upper case the result is [4, 5, 6]. However, if I change the predicate to *!d.equals(Integer.valueOf(f))* the result becomes [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. In order to solve negative predicates, I have to change the filter to:

```
.filter(d -> values.parallelStream()
                   .distinct()
                   .allMatch(f -> predicate.test(d, f))
```

But doing so destroys the positive predicates. The problem is a bit more complicated because the sample contains objects with more than one properties of different types. The BiPredicate is used to define the criteria the fulfills the filtering using values as Filter. The example above has just been simplified but correctly shows the problem I'm facing for 2 days now...

Anyone can give me a tip how I could write this lambda to work for both cases?

@Clarification:
Seeming that I failed to make one important point clear enough allow me to elaborate. That in the example I have given, I have a Collection of simple Integers doesn't mean that I'm facing this problem. Let's dive deeper...

```
class SampleDataStructure {
    PropertyType_0 property_0;
    PropertyType_1 property_1;
    ...
    PropertyType_N property_n;

    // getters defined.
}

Collection<SampleDataStructure> sample = ...; // Let's assume it has been initialized.
```

Now, Let's take an arbitrary property of SampleDataStructure (PropertyType_I property_i). That will be the key for filtering my collection. I have another collection of type PropertyType_I:

```
Collection<PropertyType_I> values = ...; //A set of values that will be used by the predicate.
```

I also have a predicate, for simplicity's sake:

```
BiPredicate<SampleDataStructure, PropertyType_I> predicateA = (data, value) -> data.getPropertyI().equals(value);
BiPredicate<SampleDataStructure, PropertyType_I> predicateB = (data, value) -> !data.getPropertyI().equals(value);
```

I want to find all SampleDataStructures that match a predicate. It can either be predicateA or predicateB. I don't know what it's going to be so use imagination. I provided these two because there're problems with my approach (see the first part of my post). Then I want to use the given converter on those SampleDataStructures and map them to something completely different and return the result in a Collection, currently Stack.

Examples:

```
sample = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
values = [4, 5, 6]

Predicate_1 = (s, v) -> s == v       Result = [4, 5, 6]
Predicate_2 = (s, v) -> s != v       Result = [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]

values = []

Predicate_1 = (s, v) -> s == v       Result = []
Predicate_2 = (s, v) -> s != v       Result = []

values = [99]

Predicate_1 = (s, v) -> s == v       Result = []
Predicate_2 = (s, v) -> s != v       Result = []
```

All this means that those proposed solutions, assuming that sample or values are only simple types are wrong. They both can be arbitrarily complex data structures and the BiPredicate is telling how the sample data should be filtered against the values. I hope that clears it up.

Here's another example:

```
class Person {
    private long id;
    String name;
    public Person(long id, String name) { this.id = id; this.name = name; }
    public long getId() { return id; }
    public Strin getName() { return name; }
}

Collection<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(new Person(1, "Jane"), new Person(2, "Doe"), new Person(3, "Jane Doe"), new Person(4, "John"), new Person(5, "whatever John"), ...);
BiPredicate<Person, String> predicate = (p, f) -> p.getName().matches(f);
Function<Person, String> personToName = Person::getName;
List<String> selectors = Arrays.asList("^Jane$", "John$");
```

As a result I want to get [ Jane, John, whatever John ]

The problem with the approach I've provided however is if I have:

```
BiPredicate<Person, String> predicate = (p, f) -> !p.getName().matches(f);
```

I'm not getting [Jane Doe, and the ... section]. I get every single item. I don't have both predicates, I showed the negative one because that doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't the "negative predicate" be `!d.equals(Integer.valueOf(f));`?

Comment: Yeah sorry that was my typo there.

Comment: I guess you need to clarify, what do you want at the end? , do you want to seperate positive and negative resulted predict's arguments to different Stack ? With a single stream? . If this is your purpose, you need to use grouping (or "partitioningBy") not filter*

Comment: No, I have a single predicate. The problem is that when I use 'negative' predicates, my solution bleeds and I can't find the reason why. Added some clarification with samples.

Comment: @Displayname the reason is obvious, your negative prediction returns true at least 1 time.How ?  your 1st collection has at least 1 element that doesn't equal to any value in 2nd collection,  consider the current element as (int) 1 from 1st collection, then dive into the filter check for negative prediction. 2nd collection has "any" element as "1" ?  no ! so your negative prediction will return true, and any anymatch will be obtained. then filter is not going to work because your all anymatch calls will return true. it would only work for 2 collection have single and same element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boolean complement of

```
anyMatch(s -> predicate.test(p, s))
```

is (according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws))

```
allMatch(s -> !predicate.test(p, s))
```

but not (as you were seemingly thinking in your post)

```
anyMatch(s -> !predicate.test(p, s))
```

Applied to your case:

```
Collection<Person> filtered = persons
            .parallelStream()
            .filter(p -> selectors.parallelStream().anyMatch(s -> predicate.test(p, s)))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Stack::new));
```

will give a collection of Persons. And

```
Collection<Person> filtered = persons
            .parallelStream()
            .filter(p -> selectors.parallelStream().allMatch(s -> !predicate.test(p, s)))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Stack::new));
```

will give the correct complementary collection of Persons.

Comment: Yeah basically IN vs NOT_IN are two completely different algorithms in this case and I can't have a single statement for them both.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more easily with `List.contains`:

```
Collection<Integer> filtered = sample.parallelStream()
                                     .filter(f -> values.contains(String.valueOf(f)))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Stack::new));
```

gives result `[4, 5, 6]`. And

```
Collection<Integer> filtered = sample.parallelStream()
                                     .filter(f -> !values.contains(String.valueOf(f)))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Stack::new));
```

gives result `[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]`.
Or did I miss something?

Comment: But he's not using `Lists`, he's using `Streams`.

Comment: And I stated that sample contains a !Complex! data structure. Also filter might contain yet again another complex data structure. With List contains we assume that those values are exactly same same. Then how about if I have a regular expression and in the BiPredicate I use that to match. This solution is not flexible enough. Predicate is there to solve this issue, I just don't know why the negative predicates cause my solution to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you what i think

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> sample = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("4", "5", "6");

    BiPredicate<Integer, String> predicate = (d, f) -> {
        return d.equals(Integer.valueOf(f));
    };

    Function<Integer, Integer> converter = Function.identity();

    Map<Integer, Boolean> filtered =
            sample.parallelStream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(intVal -> converter.apply(intVal), intVal -> values.parallelStream().noneMatch(stringVal -> predicate.test(intVal, stringVal))));

    System.out.println("filtered:");
    filtered.forEach((k,v) -> {
        System.out.println("positive:" + k + " val: " + v);
    });

}
```

result:

```
positive:0 val: true
positive:1 val: true
positive:2 val: true
positive:3 val: true
positive:4 val: false
positive:5 val: false
positive:6 val: false
positive:7 val: true
positive:8 val: true
positive:9 val: true
```

Comment: The problem was finding a single piece of code that would handle both cases correctly.

Comment: Thanks, i edited my answer but i couldnt see that in question

Comment: Looks promising but I have a Stack in the collector. I don't want to have every element, I only need the filtered ones. I can't really use this appproach for my needs I'm afraid.

Comment: You can convert, what you want! What do you have in your stack? how do you reproduce that an item is in positive case or negative case?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the [answer of Thomas Fritsch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42578679/7334796) you can do it in one line by just changing the `Predicate`. You don't need the  `BiPredicate` any more.

```
Predicate<Integer> predicate = (f) -> !values.contains(String.valueOf(f));
Predicate<Integer> predicatePositive = (f) -> values.contains(String.valueOf(f));
Function<Integer, Integer> converter = Function.identity();

Collection<Integer> filtered = sample.parallelStream()
                                    .filter(d -> values.parallelStream()
                                    .anyMatch(f -> predicate.test(d)))
                                    .map(converter)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Stack::new));
```

Comment: It would be fine if it wasn't the complex data structure. I'll update my post as it seems it wasn't emphasized enough. I just made the problem simple with having Integers in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyModel> MyModelAccountList = MyModelAccountList1.stream().filter(mymodel -> customerAcctList.stream().anyMatch(customerAccounts -> doesCustomerAccountMatch(customerAccounts, mymodel))
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: While this may answer of this question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the details  for acceptance. please provide more details